# "ARConfiguration() – init() is unavailable" error in Xcode 9 Beta 5

Tags: swift4, ios11, augmented-reality, arkit, xcode9-beta5

On updating my existing AR application code (written using ARKit and SceneKit), I am getting below error while trying to initialize ARConfiguration:

```
// ARConfiguration() - init() is unavailable.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's [documentation of `ARConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration) says:

> #### Class
>
> ## ARConfiguration
>
> The abstract base class for AR session configurations.

Seems Apple wants to make this an **abstract** class, so `init()` has made unavailable.

Can't you use any of its concrete subclasses, `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` or `AROrientationTrackingConfiguration`?